# Xamarin Essentials Package Not Resolving iOS Project

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I am getting the following error when trying to build a basic cross platform iOS app using Visual Studio for Mac (MacOS Big Sur 11.1).

error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Essentials (>= 1.5.3.2)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

I don't have a paid Apple Developer License, is this needed?

---

System Details:

Xcode Version 12.3 is installed

Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.8.6 (build 15)
Installation UUID: c45b0c40-4814-4e6b-8b98-fc071fdfd6ef
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)

Package version: 612000113

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
Mono 6.12.0.113 (2020-02/4fdfb5b1fd5) (64-bit)
Package version: 612000113

Roslyn (Language Service)
3.8.0-5.20519.18+4c195c3ac1974edcefa76774d7a59a2350ec55fa

NuGet Version: 5.8.0.6860

.NET Core SDK
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks
SDK Versions:
5.0.102
5.0.101
3.1.405
3.1.404
3.0.100
2.1.812
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET Core Runtime
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
5.0.2
5.0.1
3.1.11
3.1.10
3.0.0
2.1.24

.NET Core 3.1 SDK
SDK: 3.1.405

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.15.68
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 12.3 (17715)
Build 12C33

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 7.2.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: c51fabee8
Branch: xcode12.3
Build date: 2020-12-10 21:05:04-0500

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 14.8.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: c51fabee8
Branch: xcode12.3
Build date: 2020-12-10 21:05:05-0500

Xamarin Designer
Version: 16.8.0.510
Hash: 44e3f3ce9
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2020-12-10 00:06:14 UTC

Xamarin.Android
Not Installed

Microsoft OpenJDK for Mobile
Java SDK: Not Found

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 16.8.0.32
Hash: 01a7774
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2021-01-14 00:34:58 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 16.8.0.46
Hash: 0a81419
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-8
Build date: 2021-01-14 00:35:22 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 808060015
Git revision: d34d29b4643a130479d762e4d2b5750e6462fde7
Build date: 2021-01-15 08:35:04-05
Build branch: release-8.8
Xamarin extensions: d34d29b4643a130479d762e4d2b5750e6462fde7

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.16.0
Darwin 20.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0
Wed Dec  2 20:39:59 PST 2020
root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: is this a Xamarin Forms project?  Do you have the Essentials nuget package installed in both the shared .NET Standard project and the iOS platform project?

Comment: It is a Xamarin forms project. I have tried to add the Essentials nuget to both, but it doesn’t let me.

Comment: It looks like it is just a problem with the iOS project, though when I try to upgrade to higher version of xamarin.forms and xamarin.essentials in the xamarin.forms project it doesn't let me.

Comment: "doesn't let me" is not a helpful description of the problem.  The nuget console should show a specific error message.

Comment: Sorry, I get a warning that says "Package is not Restored". I restore by right-clicking on the solution: 
Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Essentials (>= 1.5.3.2)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1451)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

Comment: error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.3)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Essentials (>= 1.5.3.2)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.8.0.1451)' for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.

Comment: @user1837155 Hi, which action occurs this problem? Whehter it happens when you update version of MacOS or vs for mac?